# flot, jquery, asp.net - TypeError: $.plot is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flot

I know there are a few similar threads on stackoverflow but I don't use CDN in my case. I checked if the files ~/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.js and ~/Scripts/flot/jquery.colorhelpers.js exist and they do.

Here's my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FlotChart";
}

<h2>FlotChart</h2>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/flot/jquery.colorhelpers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<div id="flot-placeholder1" style="width: 300px; height: 150px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data, data1, options, chart;
    data1 = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 5], [6, 7], [7, 2], [8, 2], [9, 9]];
    data = [data1];
    options = {};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = $.plot($('#flot-placeholder1'), data, options);
    });
</script>
```

Here's my _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My Website</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        ...
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_layout.cshtml` and your `view.cshtml` both have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` so the second load of jQuery "overwrites" the first one to which Flot has been added and the `plot()` function can not be found.

And in general you should load all external JavaScript in the head not at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was not only loading jQuery twice but I should have put my javascript into

```
@Section Scripts {
}
```

Now it's rendered after jQuery is loaded in _Layout.html with the line:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Here's the correct view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FlotChart";
}

<h2>FlotChart</h2>

<div id="flot-placeholder1" style="width: 300px; height: 150px"></div>

@section Scripts
{
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/flot")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data, data1, options, chart;
        data1 = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 5], [6, 7], [7, 2], [8, 2], [9, 9]];
        data = [data1];
        options = {};

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = $.plot($('#flot-placeholder1'), data, options);
        });
    </script>
}
```